# Where to put the bean logic creation into a simple Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-annotations

it is pretty long time that I am not using Java technologies and I have some doubt if this could be a good solution to structure a Spring Boot application.

I am developing a batch application using Spring Batch into a Spring Boot application (just to explain the general context, my question should be strictly related to the Spring Boot project structure).

Basically I have this `UpdateInfoBatchApplication` that is the "main" classs starting my application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class UpdateInfoBatchApplication {
    
    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
        final String password = "MY_PSWD";
        final String pfxPath = "/home/andrea/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.11.0.RELEASE/UpdateInfoBatch/target/classes/static/certificate.pfx";
        
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory = getHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(pfxPath,password);
        
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory);
        
        return restTemplate;
        
    }
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UpdateInfoBatchApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    
    private static HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(String pfxPath,String password) throws KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                .create().loadKeyMaterial(new File(pfxPath),password.toCharArray(), password.toCharArray()).loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();

        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

        requestFactory.setHttpClient(client);
        
        return requestFactory;
    }

}
```

Basically this class contains the `main` method starting my Spring Boot application.

It also contain a `restTemplate` method annotated with `@Bean` annotation. It creates and return a custom `RestTemplate` object (it is created calling the `getHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` that itself return a `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` instance on which it is set an SSL client certificate needed to perform some APIs call).

It works fine but I am not sure that this `UpdateInfoBatchApplication` class is a good place where to put this `restTemplate` bean creation logic.

What do you think about? Could be a decent solution or is it pretty dirty?

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, it will work without problems. 2 things your `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` should be an `@Bean` to. Ideally you also want to use the `RestTemplateBuilder` which comes with a pre-configured instance (and you get the auto-configuration features of Spring Boot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your bean creation logic under a class called "BeanConfig" or sth. I mostly group them according to context they have like putting password encoder bean in SecurityBeanConfig etc. Do not forget to annotate your class

```
@Configuration
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I will have few bean (it is a pretty little batch application) but also my idea was to divide the bean creation logic from the main application class. So basically what have I to do? Have I only to create a class named BeanConfig, annotate this class with @Configuration and put inside this class the bean creation logic? tnx

Comment: yes, it will be as you said.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to separate the custom injectable beans to separate configuration classes and make sure the configuration classes' package comes under the scope of the component scan. You can refactor your code as below

**Spring boot starter class**

```
package com.demo;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class UpdateInfoBatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UpdateInfoBatchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Configuration class**

```
package com.demo;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
import org.apache.http.ssl.TrustStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

@Configuration
public class UpdateInfoBatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) {
        return new RestTemplate(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory() throws 
                            KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
                            KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
        final String password = "MY_PSWD";
        final String pfxPath = "/home/andrea/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.11.0.RELEASE" +
                                "/UpdateInfoBatch/target/classes/static/certificate.pfx";
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                            .create().loadKeyMaterial(new File(pfxPath), password.toCharArray(), password.toCharArray())
                            .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();

        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(client);
        return requestFactory;
    }
}
```